# METAFONT: Error "Can't open display"

Tags: metafont

I am trying to get started with METAFONT and I created my first glyph using [this tutorial](http://metafont.tutorial.free.fr/downloads/mftut.pdf). Unfortunately, when I run `mf beta.mf` in the command line, I receive the error message: `Letter beta [66]Error: Can't open display:`. I have googled extensively and cannot seem to find the reason for this. Could this be because the gray and black fonts were not compiled correctly? I believe I did compile those fonts correctly and my understanding is that if this were the problem, the proofsheet would simply be full of unintelligible characters; not that the viewer would not open. Here's what my `beta.mf` file looks like:

```
u#:=4/9pt#;
define_pixels(u);
beginchar(66,13u#,16u#,5u#);"Letter beta";
    x1=2u; x2=x3=3u;
    bot y1=-5u; y2=8u; y3=14u;
    x4=6.5u; top y4=h;
    z5=(10u,12u);
    z6=(7.5u,7.5u); z8=z6;
    z7=(4u,7.5u);
    z9=(11.5u,2u);
    z0=(5u,u);
    penpos1(2u,20);
    penpos2(.5u,0);
    penpos3(u,-45);
    penpos4(.8u,-90);
    penpos5(1.5u,-180);
    penpos6(.4u,150);
    penpos7(.4u,0);
    penpos8(.4u,210);
    penpos9(1.5u,-180);
    penpos0(.3u,20);
    pickup pencircle;
    penstroke z1e..z2e..z3e..z4e..z5e..z6e..{up}z7e..z8e..z9e..{up}z0e;
    labels(range 1 thru 9);
endchar;
end
```

I'm getting a little desperate and would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Im using MacTeX (TeXlive) on Mac OS Yosemite

Comment: Use `mf-nowin beta.mf` instead of `mf beta.mf` or install XQuartz from [this link](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/)

Comment: I have installed XQuartz earlier. Is a reboot required for this to work without supressing the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have an X server on your machine. Mac OS X Yosemite doesn't provide it by default.

You can install XQuartz from [this link](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) or run

```
mf-nowin beta.mf
```

Comment: Thank you! Installing X11 helped get rid of the error, but the window still doesn't open (it appears for a fraction of a second and then disappears). What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @Constantin The `end` command makes the window go away.

Comment: Thank you! The tutorial is a bit misleading as it implies that the window will open even when the `end` command is there.

Comment: Well, it *does* open; it just goes away rather quickly.  I have found that it's best to script your commands for producing proofs; a script compiling, then converting with `gftodvi`, then to pdf with `dvipdfm` (or something like it), then keeping the pdf open and reloading as needed.